# how to make bootstrap4 collapse work in vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4.3.1 and vue@2.6.10

I have this menu (is using collapse - and I don`t want to use JQuery):

```
 <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#sidebar-products" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidebar-products">
         <i class="ni ni-single-copy-04 text-primary"></i>
         <span class="nav-link-text">Products</span>
     </a>
     <div class="collapse" id="sidebar-products">
         <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item List 1</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item List 2</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </li>
```

This is only a single block that contains 2 sub-items.

What I saw using JQuery, when click on "Products" the #sidebar-products receives the .show class and aria-expanded="true".

When having multiple blocks - when click on a block to close (if there are collapsed) the others blocks.

How can I make it work the collapse with vue?

**UPDATE 1**

I created a click event that do the job:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" @click="navItemCollapse('sidebar-products', $event)" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidebar-products">
```

and the event:

```
 navItemCollapse(id, event) {
     let expanded = event.target.getAttribute('aria-expanded').toLocaleLowerCase() == 'true' ? true : false;
     let el = document.getElementById(id);
     expanded ? el.classList.remove('show') : el.classList.add('show');
                event.target.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded);
 }
```

But what if I have more blocks ? When click to open the current collapse on a block to close the others ???

Comment: Do you have the entire component code? what toggles the collapse?

Comment: I have only the html code .... `what toggles the collapse?` click on "Products" toggle the collapse (Item List 1, Item List 2)....

Comment: You can try taking a look at `bootstrap-vue` which is an implementation of Bootstrap for Vue that doesn't require jQuery

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post....I don't want to use the bootstrap-vue :) .... I want the project to keep it simple as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the implementation of no jquery

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      menuList: [{
          name: 'Products',
          expand: false,
          items: [{
              name: 'Item List 1',
              link: ''
            },
            {
              name: 'Item List 2',
              link: ''
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Others',
          expand: false,
          items: [{
              name: 'Other Item 1',
              link: ''
            },
            {
              name: 'Other Item 2',
              link: ''
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    navItemCollapse(index) {
      this.menuList = this.menuList.map((item, i) => {
        item.expand = !item.expand
        if (i !== index) {
          item.expand = false
        }
        return item
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<ul id="app">
  <li v-for="(navItem,i) in menuList" :key="i" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" :aria-expanded="navItem.expand" aria-controls="sidebar-products" @click.prevent="navItemCollapse(i)">
      <i class="ni ni-single-copy-04 text-primary"></i>
      <span class="nav-link-text">{{navItem.name}}</span>
    </a>
    <div v-if="navItem.items.length>0" class="collapse" :class="{show: navItem.expand}">
      <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
        <li v-for="(subItem,j) in navItem.items" :key="j" class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">{{subItem.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I integrate the menu data into an array of objects. Each object has an `expand` flag to determine whether it is currently expanded. When you click on the menu, switch the expand flag of the current menu.

**Note**: You don't need to care about the `id` of the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

**No jQuery or bootstrap-vue** ...

Create a function in the Component to handle the normal Bootstrap class and timing logic...

```
  data() {
    return {
      classArr: ['collapse'],
      styleObj: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleCollapse(ref) {
        let show = this.classArr.indexOf('show')>-1?false:'show'
        this.classArr = ['collapsing']
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (show){
                let height = this.$refs[ref].firstChild.clientHeight + 'px';
                this.styleObj = { height }
            }
            else {
                this.styleObj = {}  
            }
        }, 10)
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.classArr = ['collapse', show]
        }, 340)
    }
  }
```

In the component template, bind the `class` and `style` attrs to the data manipulated by the method. The ref of the specific collapse is passed in to the method...

```
  <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#sidebar-products" role="button" @click="toggleCollapse('sidebar')">
            <i class="ni ni-single-copy-04 text-primary"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Products</span>
        </a>
        <div :class="classArr" :style="styleObj" id="sidebar-products" ref="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item List 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item List 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </li>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/GA5CaNMzmc

EDIT: I updated the demo to make it scaleable for multiple collapses

Answer (score 1):

**This is a fully working version using bootstrap-vue:**

```
 <div class="accordion" role="tablist">
            <b-card v-for="(value, key) in this.jobs" :key="key" no-body class="mb-1">
              <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
                <b-button block v-b-toggle="'accordion-'+key" variant="primary">{{ value.title }}</b-button>
              </b-card-header>
              <b-collapse :id="'accordion-'+key.toString()" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
                <b-card-body>
                  <b-card-text>{{ value.specs }}</b-card-text>
                </b-card-body>
              </b-collapse>
            </b-card>
          </div>
```

Data object:

```
data() {
    return {
     jobs: [
        {
          title: 'Design artist',
          specs: 'Have an eye for web beauty'
        },
        {
          title: 'Backend guru',
          specs: 'Do stuff that don\'t break'
        },
        {
          title: 'Frontend master',
          specs: 'Create an UI that works'
        }
      ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the @sugars approach :)

So...the final version is this:

```
<li v-for="(navItem, i) in sidenavItems" class="nav-item">
                            <router-link v-if="!navItem.isCollapsible" class="nav-link" @click.native="navItemCollapse(i)" active-class="active" :to="{name: navItem.route}" exact>
                                <i :class="navItem.class"></i>
                                <span class="nav-link-text">{{ navItem.name }}</span>
                            </router-link>

                            <a v-if="navItem.isCollapsible" class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" @click="navItemCollapse(i)" data-toggle="collapse" :aria-expanded="navItem.expanded">
                                <i :class="navItem.class"></i>
                                <span class="nav-link-text">{{ navItem.name }}</span>
                            </a>
                            <div v-if="navItem.isCollapsible" class="collapse" :class="navItem.expanded ? 'show' : ''">
                                <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
                                    <li v-for="subItem in navItem.items" class="nav-item">
                                        <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: subItem.route}">{{ subItem.name }}</router-link>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

the sidenavItems:

```
 sidenavItems: [
                    {name: 'Dashboard', isCollapsible: false, route: 'dashboard', class: 'class1'},
                    {name: 'Categories', isCollapsible: false, route: 'category', class: 'class2'},
                    {name: 'Brands', isCollapsible: false, route: 'brand', class: 'class3'},
                    {name: 'Products', isCollapsible: true, expanded: false, class: 'class4', items: [{name: 'List', route: 'product'}]},
                    {name: 'Orders', isCollapsible: false, route: 'order', class: 'class5'},
                    {name: 'Blog', isCollapsible: true, expanded: false, class: 'class6', items: [{name: 'List', route: ''}]},
                ],
```

and the navItemCollapse method:

```
 navItemCollapse(index) {
     this.sidenavItems = this.sidenavItems.map( (item, i) => {
                item.expanded = !item.expanded;
                if(i !== index) {
                    item.expanded = false;
                }
                return item;
            })
        }
```

Comment: If it helps you, I hope to adopt my answer. Have a nice day :)