# Automated id increment for bootstrap collapse component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap's Collapse components require sections (or cards) with unique id to enable collapsing / decollapsing each section independently. I am trying to create multiple sections equal to the amount of data points using "v-for" from vue.js. However, I don't know how to automatically generate unique ids for the cards. this is what I tried:

```
<div id = "story-content" class="content">
        <div v-for="(subchapter, chapter) in story" class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <a href = "'collapse' + generateNewId" class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" >
                    [[chapter]]
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id = "'collapse' + getCurrentId" class="collapse show" data-parent="#story-content" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    [[subchapter]]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

<script> 
    var story = {{story | safe}};

    var app = new Vue({
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]'],
        el: '#portofolio',
        data: {
            story: story,
            uniqueId: 0,
        },
        methods: {
            generateNewId: function() {
                return uniqueId + 1;
            },
            getCurrentId: function() {
                return uniqueId;
            }
        } 
    })
</script>
```

Example of the story data structure:

```
{
    "Chapter1": {
        "Subchapter1": {
            "side_note": "January - June 2019",
            "desc": "description here"
        },
        "Subchapter2": {
            "side_note": "January - June 2019",
            "desc": "description here"
        }
    },
    "Chapter2": {
        "Subchapter1": {
            "side_note": "",
            "desc": ""
        }
    }
}
```

P.S I am not using bootstrap-vue since I did not know its existence until in the middle of my learning. I'm a beginner in web development. Hopefully there is a way to solve this issue without the need of bootstrap-vue as I will need to modify other components as well.

Comment: Added the data structure example

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 uses jQuery for the Collapse component. So, one way to solve it is to simply use the Chapter keys as the unique id's...

```
    <div id="story-content" class="content">
        <div v-for="(subchapter, chapter) in story" class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <a :href="'#collapse' + chapter" :data-target="'#collapse' + chapter" class="card-link"
                    data-toggle="collapse"> [[chapter]] </a>
            </div>
            <div :id="'collapse' + chapter" 
                class="collapse show" data-parent="#story-content">
                <div class="card-body"> [[subchapter]] </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/0DEYVY4HUA

*However*, using jQuery with Vue isn't desirable, so a better way would be to [recreate the collapse behavior in Vue as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58768851/171456)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. May I know why a mix of jQuery and Vue is not desirable? Also, I tried the above method and looked into the demo. However, I am hoping for a slightly different performance. Currently, clicking on a chapter will open the sub-chapter for that particular chapter and close for other chapters. Is it possible make the collapse-decollapse behaviour independent between chapters / cards?

I'm trying to achieve the Accordion example:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_collapse.asp